# How to authenticate to web based firewall?

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, internet

I'm new to ubuntu server and I'm trying to figure this out.

I have a server install of ubuntu 12.04 behind a fortigate firewall. To get internet access I have to authenticate with the the fortigate first. The only way I know how to is via the fortigate webpage. eg, when I type a website URL the first time I use a browser for the day, Id get redirected to the firewalls webpage thats gets my credentials before sending my to the URL.

Now how do I this if I dont have access to a GUI?
I also dont have access to the firewall (Its managed by somebody else)?

Any ideas would be help full.

Jason

Comment: Who manages the firewall? Having to login to get internet access seems pretty silly, if this is a corporate environment that would make me wonder.  It is a corporate environment right?

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/29540/browsing-the-internet-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask whoever adminsters the firewall to make an exception for your server and allow direct internet access.

This is a "problem" that servers normally do not deal with.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did as a work around.

I used another computer and downloaded "links"
Links is a text based web browser.

I copied the links.deb package to the ubuntu server. 
I installed links dpkg -i links.deb

and was able to authenticate against the firewall.

Comment: is there a better method than this?

Comment: Yes, get the firewall "problem" fixed.  This is not a normal environment.